# Custom reports in google analytics API

Tags: google-analytics

My goal is to retrieve user's custom reports which was created in Google Analytics UI from Google Analytics API.
I have registered application in Cloud console where received certificate file and generated developer email. Also configured access (granted all rights) for generated email on admin page in GA UI.
To achieve my goal I am trying get segments from service, but I am not sure it is correct way to get custom reports. As a result getting only 13 default segments (with negative Ids), it is less than I can receive in Google APIs Explorer, for example one of it

> {    "id": "9MaL7mLnQbWO3k52Ipni5A",    "kind": "analytics#segment",
>   "selfLink":
>   "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/segments/gaid::9MaL7mLnQbWO3k52Ipni5A",
>   "segmentId": "gaid::9MaL7mLnQbWO3k52Ipni5A",    "name": "Blog Comment
>   Submitters",    "definition": "ga:eventAction=@commentform"   }

My question is it correct way to get custom reports? If it is, why I am getting only default segments?

Code:

```
private readonly string scope = AnalyticsService.Scopes.Analytics.GetStringValue();

private const string clientId = "xxx-xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

private const string keyFile = @"C:\xxx-privatekey.p12";

string keyPassword = "notasecret";
```

---

```
var desc = GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description;
var key = new X509Certificate2(keyFile, keyPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

var client = new AssertionFlowClient(desc, key){
    ServiceAccountId = clientId,
    Scope = scope
};

var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>(client, AssertionFlowClient.GetState);

var gas = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer { Authenticator = auth, });

var request = gas.Management.Segments.List();

var d = request.Execute();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alexander,

I am sorry to say this, but your code won't work :-)

You are using [Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/), which has no direct access to data, but is used to manager account settings, users etc:

> With the Management API you can query for a user's account, web
>   properties, and views (profiles), determine what account segments the
>   user has configured, even retrieve information about the goals in a
>   configured view (profile).

I would suggest using [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/). Given the details of your post, I assume the technical part won't be an issue.

And to answer your question -- even though there is direct way to get you created custom report, just use the same dimension/metrics/filters/segments as you see in the web-interface.

The [query structure](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) is very straight-forward, for example:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga
  ?ids=ga:12345
  &start-date=2008-10-01
  &end-date=2008-10-31
  &metrics=ga:visits,ga:bounces
```

Comment: Petr, I do not need only visits and bounces, I have 20+ reports and I do not want to recreate them from scratch.

Comment: @AlexandrChernyshov I understand, but there is no direct way of getting the custom report structure, unfortunately. The example above was taken from Google Analytics documentation, you can of course add many more dimensions / metrics. Query Explorer might also help safe some boring work: http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

Comment: Do we need OAuth to get CUSTOM REPORTS @PetrHavlik

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot access custom reports data via the API.  There is an open feature request here:  [Expose Custom Reporting trough API](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=23&q=custom%20report&colspec=ID%20Component%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary)

The [Megalytic](http://megalytic.com) tool might be of interest to you.  It creates reports from the API which you can save as templates, share with others via email or web links, and even brand with your own cover pages or logo.  Disclaimer:  I am a founder of Megalytic.

Comment: For others interested in this feature please star and comment on the open feature request https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=23 Mark links to, the more support it gets the more likely it will be added into the API.

Comment: In 2020, I'm still looking for a similar solution.